# Why ng build just doesn’t work in the Angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular

Created a new project, did not change anything. I started ng build, took the dist folder (only it) and ran it on the local server. In the end, nothing. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question miss some precisions. 
You are trying to run your angular app on a local server. Which ?

When you build your app with ng build you build a static app. (And when you use the option *--prod* you app will be optimized for production)

Try simply with the npm library http-server **AND note that currently there is a bug in the latest version of this library ! So try the version @0.9 for example**.

Maybe this is it you already try with the latest version and you see nothing so..

Hope this helps.

Comment: I put the entire dist folder on the server (https://artartem.000webhostapp.com/my-dream-app/index.html) and it does not work there either. Just a white screen and that's it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know this server.. And it is not a **local** server in fact. You have to look at this address https://artartem.000webhostapp.com/my-dream-app/ . And regarding to the logs there is a probleme of paths to reach your js file.. You need these files for running the app. I think you must set the baseref to "my-dream-app" in your case

Comment: You can see in your index.htm you have <base href="/"> and for your server its means /public_html but when it try to looking for files inside this folder it found nothing of course so set it to <base href="/my-dream-app">

Comment: I tested on a local and cloud hosting and at first everything did not work the same. But when I added ng build --prod --aot, on the local server (OSPANEL) on the local server it works well, but it does not work on the webhosting.

Answer (score 0):

So i followed your link and used the view source to see what your base href is. Currently, your base href in your index.html is set to:

```
 <base href="/my-dream-app">
```

if you change this to:

```
<base href="https://artartem.000webhostapp.com/my-dream-app/index.html">
```

your application should run as intended.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome. Please up vote and accept this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand your point. When you use the build command, you are compiling to production, I mean, you are transpiling from typescript to javascript vanilla, in less words, you are preparing your angular application to speak the same browser language.

Sorry, but I answer you as I understand your problem.

Comment: It's clear. But after I compiled the application and put it on the server, it shows a blank page.